# How to target child class and hide the parent one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I'm working with a third-party code and I'm quite limited in terms of filtering a list of elements.

Each of these elements has this structure:

```
<div class="item-preview">
   <div class="item-info">
      <div class="tag">
         <svg class="tag-public"></svg>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The only thing that changes is the svg class, so it's whether `tag-public` or `tag-private`. Depending on the user type that's checking the content, I'd like to hide it when  it's `tag-private`. Something like:

```
if user == x_member_type
   if item-preview CONTAINS tag-private
      HIDE item-preview
```

Is there any way possible to target that parent div so I can work with that? I've tried with jQuery's parent, closest, etc. but I'm not getting any results.

For whatever reason, it is not working. I guess it's getting the list of elements via AJAX and displaying it and my added jQuery doesn't make any difference.

Do you have any ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: Why isn't it just `$('.tag-private').closest('.item-preview').hide()`?

Comment: For whatever reason, this is not working either. I guess it's getting the list of elements via AJAX and displaying it and my added jQuery doesn't affect it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could be. Depends on when it runs. You'd have to show more about your situation.